# How to add facebook like button to tumblr blog?

Tags: html, facebook, tumblr

A lot of people seem to have this problem and the reason is - no one provided good enough solution. Please help get facebook like button on tumblr that actually works. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a simple full [tutorial](http://forum.developers.facebook.net/viewtopic.php?pid=238518) for adding both the like-button and the comments-box plugins on Tumblr.

Comment: Please see ["How could I write my answer that links to an external resource properly?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/94022/how-could-i-write-my-answer-that-links-to-an-external-resource-properly). I know you've come up against these guidelines before and edited your answers to comply, so please take the time to make sure you comply with them first, before you post.

Comment: @Anna Lear - Me? Came against? mmm...no I didn't, I just didn't know I'm not allowed to use short-urls (I'm new here) but nothing more. and here it's not a short-url so I don't see what's the problem please? It's not a self promotion, and I'm not going to post a full long tutorial here all over in each time there is a need for it (you know). or does the problem in this post is that I should always "name" the links and never show the full url maybe? sorry but I honestly don't understand, so please let me know so I can learn.

Comment: Sorry, my bad. I misinterpreted some of the actions on your answers from earlier. :) Still, check out the link I posted in my comment. The issue isn't so much the kind of link you use (although short urls are discouraged), but rather that links die in general and a good answer has the important parts in the answer itself with the link provided as a reference. You don't have to copy the entire content of the link (in fact, it's better if you don't :)), but summarizing it so that the answer can stand on its own would be great. Thanks.

Comment: @Anna Lear - Thanks, Can you please unblock me and let me keep answer on questions?

Comment: Are you getting a message along the lines of "we are no longer accepting answers from this account"? Unfortunately it's an automatic ban and moderators don't have any way to remove it. If your existing answers attract upvotes, that might help, but the details of the algorithm aren't public, so it's hard to tell.

Comment: @Anna Lear - Yep that's the error message I keep getting when trying to post an answer.
Great, so now I'm stuck LOL.